# iOS app for Google search

Tags: ios

I am trying to build an app for iOS where we search for images based on user input, and responses will be returned by Google search for images. Do we have a Google search API which returns the aforesaid results?

Answer (score 0):

The [Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/) has been deprecated since 2011. Use [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) instead.